# space of continuous functions C(X,R): can one make it compact by making the domain X compact?

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider a set of sequences $u(t)$ with discrete index $t=1,2,...$ where $u(t)\in[a,b]$, i.e. all values are taken from a finite interval. The space of such sequences is not compact. To make it compact one would have to limit the range for the index variable $t\in\{1,2,...,n\}$. (The space $[a,b]^n$ is compact).

What if the index $t$ is continous (and we are looking at continuous functions)? Would the similar reasoning work?

For example, I presume (I am not sure) that the set of all continuous functions $f$ such that
$$
f : [0,\infty) \rightarrow [a,b]
$$
is not compact since the range of the index (the domain of the function) is infinite. Can one claim that if I made the domain finite, then the space of all continuous functions $f$ would be compact? Namely, would the space of continous functions
$$
f : [0,T] \rightarrow [a,b]
$$
be compact then?

Comment: Look at the Arzéla Ascoli theorem. $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ in general is not compact but you can characterize the compact subsets!